# Save information from quiz in list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, survey-list, survey

I have a quiz in SharePoint.

It works perfectly but what I want is:

After a student have taken the quiz, I would like a list named `quizlist` to store information for the users who has taken the quiz to show what the score he/she got and to show the user name.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using the survey app?

Comment: something like that

Comment: You should give more details about how you have implemented the quiz so far. Is it a OOTB Survey or custom implementation (SP app or PHA or page with jsom/csom etc)

Comment: var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = resultList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    listItem.set_item("Student", UserName);
    listItem.set_item("TestDate", dtm);
    listItem.set_item("Score", (score / testQuestions) * 100);
    listItem.set_item("QuizID", currentQuizItem.get_id());
    listItem.update();

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to save information in a list. Check following and find which suites you best.

- [Using Server Object Model C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467435(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Using Client Object Model C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Using Client Object Model Javascript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Using REST API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: // Store the score for the current user
   `var dtm = new Date();`
   ` var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();`
  `  var listItem = resultList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);`
    `listItem.set_item("Student", UserName);``
    listItem.set_item("TestDate", dtm);
    listItem.set_item("Score", (score / testQuestions) * 100);
    listItem.set_item("QuizID", currentQuizItem.get_id());
    listItem.update();
    context.load(listItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        $('#TestUI').fadeOut(500, function () { $('#TestReport').fadeIn(500, null) });
    },`
howto store?

Comment: add some description in your comment. what do you mean? add this code in your question. it is not readable from comment

Comment: i have the following method inside of my code i have to modify this code and to store my information on my desire list!

Comment: Is it your code or you got it from somewhere?

Comment: yes from microsoft

Comment: as you said that your code is taken from microsoft. So it's time to modify it properly like list name, column name and so on. Before that you need to read the documentation properly